# C++ map showing values as 0 for all keys

Tags: c++, c++14

I am inserting number from a vector in map with key as the number and value as it's (index + 1).
But when I print the contents of the map, value being shown is 0 though I pass interger i.

```
// taking input of n integers in vector s;
vector<int> s;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int tmp;cin>>tmp;
    s.push_back(tmp);
}
//creating map int to int
map<int,int> m;
bool done = false;
for(int i=1;i<=s.size();i++){
   //check if number already in map
   if (m[s[i-1]]!=0){
       if (i-m[s[i-1]]>1){
          done = true;
          break;
       }
    }
    // if number was not in map then insert the number and it's index + 1
    else{
          m.insert({s[i-1],i});
    }
}
for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++){
    cout<<endl<<it->first<<": "<<it->second<<endl;
}
```

For input 
n = 3 
and numbers as 
`1 2 1` in vector s, I expect the output to be

```
1: 1
2: 2
```

but output is

```
1: 0
2: 0
```

Why 0? What's wrong?

Comment: Hi! Just as a recommendation, I'd recommend you using 0-based indexing in the loop, so that all `i-1` go away.

Comment: I am using 1 based indexing because if the number never came before, its value is shown as 0 but even if the first number came before then also it's value will be 0 so there will be confusion. Can you please tell why 0 is shown in values? I noticed that - in the for loop, if i remove if else statements and then use same insert command then correct output is coming. Why?

Comment: it is easier to help you when you post a [mcve]. Only little is missing, includes, and a main, but it is already enough to make me think twice if I should copy your code and add the missing pieces to get it compile

Comment: @idclev463035818 Oh! Yes, I should keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @kjhf `std::map` also requires unique keys (and `std::map::insert` also returns a pair of iterator and bool, same like `std::unordered_map::insert`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code block following the comment:

```
// check if number already in map
```

is logically faulty, because `operator[]` will actually *insert* an element, using value initialisation<sup>(a)</sup>, if it does not currently exist.

If you were to instead use:

```
if (m.find(s[i-1]) != m.end())
```

that would get rid of this problem.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I believe<sup>(b)</sup> that value initialisation for *classes* involve one of the constructors; for *arrays,* value initialisation for each item *in* the array; and, for *other types* (this scenario), zero initialisation. That would mean using your method creates an entry for your key, with a zero value, and returns that zero value

It would then move to the `else` block (because the value is zero) and try to do the insert. However, this snippet from the standard (`C++20, [map.modifiers]` discussing `insert`) means that nothing happens:

> If the map already contains an element whose key is equivalent to `k`, there is no effect.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> Though, as my kids will point out frequently, and without much prompting, I've been wrong before :-)

Comment: @idclev463035818 AFAIK the standard does not force default int value to be 0. In fact most compilers will use whatever is on top of the stack at the moment.

Comment: @freakish But [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) requires that it is zero-initialized for non-class types.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you are right. But still compilers don't do that. I've just checked the std::map implementation (gcc) and no zero-initialization is there. Perhaps a bug?

Comment: @freakish then you must have missed it, I wrote lots of code that relies on this and it always worked as expected. `operator[]` uses the default constructor which for an `int` is just zero-initialization

Comment: @freakish gcc does [value initialize mapped_type](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h#L505), which for `int` would be zero-initialization. Not sure about other compilers.

Comment: @freakish I was basing on cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization "The effects of value initialization are: ... 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized."

Answer (score 3):

[`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) will create a default element if it doesn't exist. Because you do `m[s[i-1]]` in the `if` condition, `m.insert({s[i-1],i});` in else branch will *always* fail.

To check if key is already present in map use either [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), [`count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) or [`contains()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) (if your compiler supports C++20)

```
//either will work instead of `if (m[s[i-1]]!=0)`
if (m.find(s[i-1]) != m.end()) 
if (m.count(s[i-1]) == 1)
if (m.contains(s[i-1])) //C++20
```